# MPLS labels for BGP prefixes

Tags: cisco, mpls

I've just started studying about MPLS and the labels it uses and this was mentioned in my study resource.

*When we use LDP on Cisco IOS, we locally generate a label for each prefix that we can find in the RIB, **except for BGP prefixes**. This information is then added to the LIB (Label Information Base)*

When I tried to lab this myself, none of the BGP prefixes had an entry and a label in the MPLS Forwarding Table, just like mentioned above. It turned out that BGP prefixes are resolved to their next hop IP addresses and the labels allocated for the next-hop addresses are also used for BGP prefixes.

My question is, why does it work this way with BGP? I've only covered basic MPLS so far and this kinda caught me off guard.

Thank you, everyone.

Comment: Giving a comprehensive answer would be quite the undertaking given that you've only covered basic MPLS. For context, MPLS is the label _switching_ protocol and LDP (and RSVP) is for the label _distribution_ that MPLS uses. The behavior your seeing for BGP is the more common use case. BGP and MPLS _can_ be used together but are by no means required by each other in all applications.